# Is it possible to use Get-AzureADServicePrincipal and Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment to remove users access to all azure enterprise apps?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to automate the removal all enterprise app access for terminated employee's with powershell but can not figure out if its possible to store all of a users app assignments to a variable and then remove them from all app assignments stored in that variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, there is no such cmdlets to directly assign variable to a user for all the apps that are assigned to that user. Rather than that, you can add all the terminated employees(users)to a group and then assign a variable to them for unassigning them from an application. An example of the same is as follows: -

$group = get-azureadgroup -ObjectId

$spo = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId

$assignments = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spo.ObjectId | Where {$_.PrincipalDisplayName -eq $group.DisplayName}

$assignments | Select *
Remove-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spo.ObjectId -AppRoleAssignmentId
$assignments[assignment #].ObjectId

Also, find the below links for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/disable-user-sign-in-portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/manage-application-permissions

Thanking you,

Comment: hi is assignment # the AppRoleAssignmentId? my co-worker is telling me i dont need your line of $spo = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId

Comment: Might be you don't need it, but you can try executing the code in your UAT environment. Thanks